# Embedd a flash element and make unclickable

Tags: html, embed, swfobject

I am trying to embed this flash banner in side but url on it is messed up. 
So I placed an invisible div on it with the correct url . 
The trouble is when I click on it, I get transferred to both the correct url and the incorrect one.

```
<div class="invisible" onmousedown="window.open('http://ags.gns.co.il/cdn/DigitalCloud/iMarkets/2012/Gadi_Back_To_News/?Media=maof')" style="z-index:10000">
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/Imarkets_150x75.swf" width="150" height="75">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/Imarkets_150x75.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
   </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overlaying the flash, you are just containing it !
try this html:

```
<div class="invisible">
   <a class="overlay" href="http://ags.gns.co.il/cdn/DigitalCloud/iMarkets/2012/Gadi_Back_To_News/?Media=maof"></a>
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/Imarkets_150x75.swf" width="150" height="75">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/Imarkets_150x75.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
   </object>
</div>​​​
```

now we set the link to overlay the flash

```
.invisible{
 position:relative;
 width:150px;
 height:75px;
}
.​overlay{
 z-index:10000; 
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 height:75px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 background:red; 
 opacity:0.3;    
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/FvhVC/2/)**
you can remove the opacity and background, they are just for demonstration.

Comment: actually, I noticed that in IE8 the transparency doesn't work - so Ichanged the background to tranparent -> and it stoped working. (p.s you have ';;' in the height )

Comment: here's an updated fiddle as workaround 
http://jsfiddle.net/FvhVC/3/
but i will see why it doesn't work when you remove the background or set it to transparent !